# How to get moved image detail as alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 4 images on top of my web page(in a table) and another 4 images on bottom of my page(in another table).
And I have two buttons named "Move" & "Getdata"
when I click move the images in bottom of screen will fly and fix over the images shown on top table.

My query is, after moving the image I press the 'Get Data' button that not shown the moved images detail as alert.That shown only the first placed image detail.
HTML code:

```
 <div id="ans">
<table id="ansTable" >
  <tr>
      <td id="td1" >
      <img id="img1" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/100/100/" draggable="false"/>
       </td>
    <td  id="td2"  >
      <img id="img2" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/h/100/100/" draggable="false"/>
       </td>
    <td id="td3" >
     <img id="img3" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/i/100/100/" draggable="false"/>
       </td>
    <td id="td4"  >
     <img id="img4" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/j/100/100/" draggable="false"/>
       </td>
     </tr>
</table>
</div>

<br/><br/><br/>

<button id ="btnMove"   class="myButton">Done</button>

<button id ="btnGetdata"   class="myButton">Get Data</button>


<div id="Ques" style="padding-left:200px;padding-top:200px">
<table id="quesTable" >
  <tr>
      <td id="ftd1" >
      <img id="fly1" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/c/100/100/" draggable="false"/>
       </td>
    <td  id="ftd2"  >
      <img id="fly2" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/l/100/100/" draggable="false"/>
       </td>
    <td id="ftd3" >
     <img id="fly3" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/m/100/100/" draggable="false"/>
       </td>
    <td id="ftd4"  >
     <img id="fly4" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/n/100/100/" draggable="false"/>
       </td>
     </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

JQuery code:

```
$("#btnGetdata").click(function () {
     var table = document.getElementById('ansTable');
  var data=table.rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML;
    alert(data);
});


$("#btnMove").click(function () {

 var v = $("#fly1").offset();
  var p = $("#img3").offset();
 $("#fly1").css({ "top": v.top + "px", "left": v.left + "px" , "position": "absolute"});

    $("#fly1").animate({
        opacity: 1,
         top: p.top,
         left: p.left
    }, 1000);


 var v = $("#fly2").offset();
 var p = $("#img1").offset();
 $("#fly2").css({ "top": v.top + "px", "left": v.left + "px" , "position": "absolute"});

    $("#fly2").animate({
        opacity: 1,
         top: p.top,
         left: p.left
    }, 1000);

var v = $("#fly3").offset();
var p = $("#img4").offset();
 $("#fly3").css({ "top": v.top + "px", "left": v.left + "px" , "position": "absolute"});

    $("#fly3").animate({
        opacity: 1,
         top: p.top,
         left: p.left
    }, 1000);

var v = $("#fly4").offset();
var p = $("#img2").offset();
 $("#fly4").css({ "top": v.top + "px", "left": v.left + "px", "position": "absolute" });

    $("#fly4").animate({
        opacity: 1,
         top: p.top,
         left: p.left
    }, 1000);
});
```

This is the worked out Jsfiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/a09bshb7/41/

Kindly help me out for the same.
Thanks,
Prem

Comment: you are not replacing the previous images. You are positioning(animating) you new images which doesn't update your first image container.

Comment: Thank you I got it. Can you please guide me how to replace the previous image?

Comment: as mentioned in my answer, use .replaceWith() to replace an element .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, you are animating the bottom ("**#quesTable**") images to the top images ("**#ansTable**") position which doesn't necessarily update the parent div ("**#ansTable**") contents of the top positioned images.

Update your ***$("#btnMove").click();*** bottom section adding these lines of code :

```
$("<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>").insertAfter("#ans"); // to keep your buttons on fixed position. You can handle it using css also.
$("#ansTable tr").replaceWith($("#quesTable tr"));
$("#Ques").remove();
```

and ***$("#btnGetdata").click();*** event as follow :

```
$("#btnGetdata").click(function () {
    $("#ansTable tr td").each(function(){
        alert($(this).children("img").attr("id"));
    });
});
```

Here you are updating the position of you images when you are clicking the DONE button and also you replace the ansTable content with quesTable content.

For that I used [***.replaceWith()***](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) method of jQuery.

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/3Lwufrrj/)

Comment: Thanks Ashad please check the link below I tried as you said,http://jsfiddle.net/a09bshb7/45/

Comment: Isn't it what you want?

Comment: Let me explain my scenario again, on page load, I am hitting "GetId" button, It shows alert as Img1,Img2,Img3.. okay.                        Now I am hitting "Done" button which moves the images below to top of my page. Now I am clicking "GetId" button, it should show alert as Fly1,Fly2,Fly3....That's it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I was able to understand Check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/a09bshb7/42/

If this is what you want to implement.

```
$("#btnGetdata").on('click',function () {
           $('#ansTable tr td').each(function(){
           alert($(this).find('img').attr('id'));
        });
    });
```

Comment: still you are displaying the information of the previous images.

Comment: Thanks vinita for the response.But I need to get the id of the flied image.any ideas?

Comment: Ok got that. Check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/a09bshb7/43/ . Hope this will help.

Comment: Check updated code for the same. Link for this : http://jsfiddle.net/a09bshb7/44/

Comment: Thanks again vinita .But I need to get the id of the flied image after clicking Done button.i.e fly1,fly2,fly3,fly4

Comment: @VinitaRathore, OP wants to alert the updated image that was moved from bottom to top after clicking DONE & GetData. So the result should display : "<img id="fly1" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/c/100/100/" draggable="false"/>". If I'm not wrong.

Comment: Replace "$('#ansTable tr td').each(function(){" with "$('#quesTable tr td').each(function(){"